# Rspec + Shoulda + FactoryGirl = undefined method `reflect_on_association'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda, factory-bot

I have Rspec + Shoulda + FactoryGirl and I am receiving the following error when attempting to call Shoulda's have_many or belong_to methods. All Shoulda methods used in the "validations" group work fine:

```
>   NoMethodError in 'A Project
> associations should When you call a
> matcher in an example without a
> String, like this:
> 
>   specify { object.should matcher }
> 
>   or this:
> 
>   it { should matcher }
> 
>   RSpec expects the matcher to have a
> #description method. You should either   add a String to the example this
> matcher is being used in, or give it a
> description method. Then you won't
> have to suffer this lengthy warning
> again.   '   undefined method
> `reflect_on_association' for
> #<Project:0x34d8624>   /vendor/plugins/active_matchers/lib/matchers/association_matcher.rb:37:in
> `confirm_association'  
> /vendor/plugins/active_matchers/lib/matchers/association_matcher.rb:36:in
> `each'  
> /vendor/plugins/active_matchers/lib/matchers/association_matcher.rb:36:in
> `confirm_association'  
> /vendor/plugins/active_matchers/lib/matchers/association_matcher.rb:11:in
> `matches?'  
> ./spec/models/project_spec.rb:7:
```

Thanks in advance

## spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'shoulda'
```

## spec/models/project_spec.rb

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe "A Project" do
  describe "associations" do

    subject { Factory(:project) }

    it { should have_many(:tasks) }
    it { should belong_to(:project_status) }
  end

  describe "validations" do
    subject { Factory(:project) }

    it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }

    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).case_insensitive }

    it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:name) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to David C. for pointing out what should have been obvious. I had a redundant active_matchers plugin that was conflicting with shoulda.

Comment: He is probably talking about this https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/204841 I guess